# How do to bind x11vnc to localhost only and tunnel through SSH?

Tags: ssh-tunneling, vnc

There are [many good answers on how to tunnel VNC traffic using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/a/304720/27088). When doing something like...

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 x11vnc
```

...you can connect to the SSH tunnel on localhost:5900 (on the client side) to the SSH. But isn't host:5900 also open for attackers? How can I make x11vnc listening *only* to the traffic comming from the SSH tunnel?

I'd prefer something temporary and not messing around with iptables or so.

<s>I think the `-listen` parameter is *not* what I need, because it listens to the *interface* with the given IP address:</s>

```
-listen ipaddr         listen for connections only on network interface with
                       addr ipaddr. '-listen localhost' and hostname work too.
```

...copied from [here](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html).

Comment: why not have x11vnc listen on the loopback IP addres of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @thrig uhh yes... Thank you! I forgot that this was a separate interface... I tried it out and noticed 5900 was open from outside. But actually there was a x11vnc process still running without `-listen localhost`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that `-listen` *is* what I need. By listening to the device with addr `localhost` it listens only to the loopback device:

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 x11vnc -listen localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question when you got it to work. This helps all of us.

Answer (score 2):

For me -listen localhost doesn't worked for ipv6 , and found the correct option is -localhost , man page (man x11vnc) says basically the same as "-allow 127.0.0.1".

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 x11vnc -localhost
```